# Expand python matrix along extra dimension

Tags: python, arrays, matrix-multiplication

I have a 2 dimensional `3x3` array e.g.:

```
(4,5,6

 8, 10, 12

 12,15,18 )
```

I would like to multiply this by a vector `(1,2,3)` so that I end up with a `3x3x3` array where along the third dimension all the elements of the original array are multiplied by 1, 2 or 3 respectively. How do it do this in python?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890621/matrix-and-array-multiplication-in-numpy

Comment: Do you mean a `numpy` array? A list of lists? What have you tried so far, and what happened?

Answer (score 0):

This is the shortest code i could come up with (not the most optimized):

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
b = [1,2,3]
mult = [[[z*x for z in y] for y in a] for x in b]
```