# What is the definition of multiplication of jagged/ragged Numpy.array?

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I do not understand what happens when multiplying Numpy.arrays.

For example, with with jagged (or ragged) arrays

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[100,200]])
b = np.array([2, 4])
print(a * b)
```

I get

```
[[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3] [100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200]]
```

But, if I modify a little

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2],[100,200]])
b = np.array([2, 4])
print(a * b)
```

I get

```
[[  2   8]
[200 800]]
```

I want to find the definition of array multiplication.

Answer (score 3):

Your main problem is that your array `a` isn't a "normal" array, because the second dimensions are not equal.
If you try `a.shape` you get `(2,)`, `a.dtype` gives `dtype('O')` (meaning object), and `a[0].dtype` leads to the attribute error `'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'`.
This means that you have a numpy array of dimension 2, each containing a python list.

You should look up [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), but it's not the root cause here. It's usually intended to expand dimensions of size `1` to larger values if the arrays don't match during operations. There's a lot more to it, but the documentation is pretty clear.
For your specific problem it suffices to say that broadcasting means numpy does not throw an error if the dimensions of two arrays match or one of them is 1 (counting from back to front, filling empty values with 1).

You have two `(2,)` arrays (`a` containing 2 lists, `b` containing 2 integers), which means that the dimensions fit (no broadcasting necessary).

The rest of this "misbehavior" (it isn't) has nothing to do with numpy, because in standard python (which comes into play because `a` contains python lists) multiplying a list with a scalar duplicates and appends the list that often.

So

```
>>>[1, 2, 3] * 3
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

and the same thing happens in your case: the first list in `a` gets multiplied by `2` and the second list by `4`.

Answer (score 0):

I think its "replicating ('a' array column [x]) ('b' array index [x])times".
If your objective is doing multiplication, use NP.dot instead

Comment: After I had written my answer I finally understood yours. You managed to express it much more succinctly. However, `np.dot` does not work much better, because the underlying problem of an array containing lists still exists.

Comment: You can go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890621/how-does-multiplication-differ-for-numpy-matrix-vs-array-classes there are wonderful explanation which i think you will be interested

Comment: Your are right, there are a lot of good answers behind that link. However, non of them are pertinent to this question here, where the problem isn't really the multiplication but the (very non-standard) jagged array.

Comment: `np.tensordot` has an example of string replication.

Answer (score 0):

An example in the `np.tensordot` docs might help.  It creates a object array of strings, and shows that `dot` produces string replication.

For strings and list `*` means replication

```
In [134]: 'abc'*3
Out[134]: 'abcabcabc'
```

Your arrays:

```
In [126]: a
Out[126]: array([[1, 2, 3], [100, 200]], dtype=object)
In [127]: b
Out[127]: array([2, 4])
```

and a string array (I could have also done `a[:]=['a','B']`)

```
In [128]: c = np.array(['a','B'],dtype=object)
In [129]: c
Out[129]: array(['a', 'B'], dtype=object)
```

element multiplication - replicate the elements of `a` 2 and 3 times.

```
In [130]: a*b
Out[130]: array([[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], [100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200]], dtype=object)
```

`dot` product - same thing, but it 'sums' the values after * - and sum for list is concatenation.

```
In [131]: a.dot(b)
Out[131]: [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200]
```

Same thing happens with the array of characters, replication and concatenation.

```
In [132]: c*b
Out[132]: array(['aa', 'BBBB'], dtype=object)
In [133]: c.dot(b)
Out[133]: 'aaBBBB'
```

When dealing with an object dtype array, numpy essentially iterates over the elements and applies the operator/method defined the class of that object.

`a*b` is in effect

```
In [147]: [i*j for i,j in zip(a,b)]
Out[147]: [[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], [100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200]]
```

The numpy version is a little fancier in that can handle multidimensional arrays and use broadcasting.

Answer (score -1):

Basically the numpy array a*b returns elementary multiplication and the multiplication should work like this.

Eg-1

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
b = np.array([[5,6],[7,8]])
print(a * b)
```

Output:

```
[[ 5 12] [21 32]]
```

Eg-2

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
b = np.array([5,6])
print(a * b)
```

Output:

```
[[ 5 12] [15 24]]
```

Comment: That is to say, there is a requirement for the form of an array. right?

Comment: Your first example is misbehaving because of inconsistency in the lengths of each list.

Comment: yes, but for this kind of behavior, where the official document can be viewed

Comment: I know this website,but I can not find what I look for

Comment: first example is misbehaving, This is probably what I want.

Comment: This answers the question in the title, not the question in the body.