# multiplication matrices python

Tags: python, multiplication

I have the following variables:

A of dimensions [126 X 3] 
B of dimensions [3 x 2]

what is the python equivalent of the matlab multipication
C = A*B'

C is a matrix of dimension [126 x 2]

Comment: numpy.dot or numpy.matmul https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how does multiplication differ for NumPy Matrix vs Array classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890621/how-does-multiplication-differ-for-numpy-matrix-vs-array-classes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

c = np.dot(a, b)
```

Answer (score 1):

For Python 3.5 or later, you can use the `@` matrix multiplication operator:

```
C = A@B
```