# Combining multiple perspectiveTransforms into one transform with opencv

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I have an application that has two perspective transforms obtained from two findHomography calls that get applied in succession to a set of points (python):

```
pts = np.float32([ [758,141],[769,141],[769,146],[758,146] ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
pts2 = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts, trackingM)
dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts2, updateM)
```

I would like to combine this into a single transformation.  I've tried the following but the transformation is not correct:

```
M = trackingM * updateM
dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts, M)
```

How can I combine two matrix transforms into a single transform? For now I'm prototyping in python.  A C++ solution in addition to python would be a bonus.

Answer (score 1):

In `numpy`, `np.multiply(M, N)` is `elementwise-product`, while `np.dot(M,N)` is `dot-product`. I think, in your case, you should choose `np.dot`.

---

For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np 
>>> x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

## elementwise-product 
>>> x*x
array([[ 1,  4],
       [ 9, 16]])
>>> np.multiply(x,x)
array([[ 1,  4],
       [ 9, 16]])

## dot-product
>>> x.dot(x)
array([[ 7, 10],
       [15, 22]])
>>> np.dot(x,x)
array([[ 7, 10],
       [15, 22]])
```

Comment: It is not obvious why the dot-product would combine the two transforms into one. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Demosthenes If you have learned advanced math, then you should know how to calc `dot_product`. Or go to wiki to learn: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product

Comment: I'm slightly offended by that, having a PhD in computer science, but you can't know that. I didn't say the answer was wrong (I didn't down-vote it), I just suggested it might be worthwhile explaining why this combines the two transformations, since that was the original question.

Comment: If I said `obviously, you should use dot-product other than element-wise-product`, it also doesn't help. I can't explain why,  just intuition, so I give my solution. Or, let me ask first, why use `element-wise product`?

Comment: I tried the dot product operation and can verify the resulting transform was ill formed.  I did find a solution though which I've posted.

Answer (score 1):

Let us say, we have a series of Perspective Transformation as follows. Let t<sup>i</sup><sub>j</sub> be the perspective transform matrix from image_i to image_j

image_1 **-- t<sup>1</sup><sub>2</sub> -->** image_2 **-- t<sup>2</sup><sub>3</sub> -->** .... **-- t<sup>N-1</sup><sub>N</sub> -->** image_N

The point p<sub>1</sub> in image_1 would be transformed to point p<sub>2</sub> in image_2 as **p<sub>2</sub> = t<sup>1</sup><sub>2</sub>.p<sub>1</sub>**

The point p<sub>2</sub> in image_2 would be transformed to point p<sub>3</sub> in image_3 as **p<sub>3</sub> = t<sup>2</sup><sub>3</sub>.p<sub>2</sub> = t<sup>2</sup><sub>3</sub>.t<sup>1</sup><sub>2</sub>.p<sub>1</sub>**

Hence **p<sub>N</sub> = t<sup>N-1</sup><sub>N</sub>...t<sup>2</sup><sub>3</sub>.t<sup>1</sup><sub>2</sub>.p<sub>1</sub>**

Hence the resultant transformation matrix **t<sup>1</sup><sub>N</sub> = t<sup>N-1</sup><sub>N</sub>...t<sup>2</sup><sub>3</sub>.t<sup>1</sup><sub>2</sub>**

Hence you can get M = np.dot(updateM, trackingM)

Note that all products are matrix (np.dot) products.

Answer (score 0):

I found a clue to the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890621/how-does-multiplication-differ-for-numpy-matrix-vs-array-classes).  In essence my original code was doing element-wise multiplication as pointed out by @Silencer. The trick is to convert the transform to a matrix before doing the multiply:

```
M = np.matrix(updateM) * np.matrix(trackingM)
dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts, M)
```

The order of the operands is significant.  One can think of the above as applying the updateM transformation to the trackingM transform to match the order stated in the original problem.